# WCF c# invocarlo en IONIC

Tags: c#, wcf

He creado un servicio WCF que si lo pruebo desde el WCF test client funcionan a la perfección sus metodos, el problema, es que me gustaria usarlo por ejemplo para una aplicacion en IONIC.

No tengo nocion si es posible, por lo pronto, he intentado ver sus metodos usando POSTMAN, y no he tenido suerte, siempre me sale el error 400.

Adjunto parte de mi codigo:

Servicio:

```
[WebGet]
 public List<Users> UsersList()
 {
    return Logic.LogicFabric.GetLogicUsers().List();
 }
```

IServicio:

```
[OperationContract]
 [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/UsersList/",ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
  BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
  List<Users> UsersList();
```

Webconfig:

```
<system.serviceModel>
 <services>
  <service name="JsonPrueba">
    <endpoint address="http://localhost/JsonPrueba/" binding="wsHttpBinding" 
     bindingConfiguration="EnlaceWCF" contract="IService"/>
  </service>
 </services>
 <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
 <bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="EnlaceWCF"></binding>

  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
    multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

Podrian ayudarme por favor?

Adjunto Captura de como lo hago en WCF test client y como lo hago en postman

[image: WCF TEST CLIENT]

[image: POSTMAN]

Comment: ¿Puedes [edit] tu pregunta y agregar cómo estás consumiendo los servicios *tanto en WCF Test Client como en Postman*? Creo que el error 400 es porque no estás "construyendo" correctamente la petición al servicio, pero, creo que ayudaría si aportas esta información.

Comment: Claro, Muchas Gracias!

En WCF testclient simplemente lo agrego y ya me lista los metodos

http://localhost/ServiceWCF/WCFService.svc
   IWCFService (BasicHttpBinding_IWCFService)


en postman, intento hacer lo mismo, pero agregandole un /nombremetodo

Eso es lo que tu preguntas?